# Is there any method to clear all widget and recreate same widget like a refreshing screen to take new inputs in tkinter python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Like a refreshing window it should clear all information in entries clear all checkboxes and spinbox

Comment: To clear an entry use `<tk.Entry>.delete(0, "end")`. Can you show us how you created the `checkboxes` and `spinbox`?

Comment: root = Tk() ... sp = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=tsr_get_qu).place(x=390, y=250, w=40, h=20)....l12rateF = Checkbutton(root, text="200/-", variable=tsr_val2, font="Times_New_Roman 10", justify=CENTER,command=l12rf_amt, onvalue=200, offvalue=0) .place(x=315, y=250, w=50, h=20)

Comment: Try using `tsr_get_qu.set(0)`

Comment: like this i have more than 30 checkboxes

Comment: Did you put them in a list?

Comment: no they are displayed in same way i have written before

Comment: can you tell me how to add it into a list?

Comment: you should keep elements on list and then you can use `for`-loop to execute the same command on all elements. And how to list you should already know - create list at start `all_checkboxes = []` and add checkboxes when you create them `all_checkboxes.append( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def print_all():
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.get())
    for var in spinbox_vars:
        print(var.get())
    for var in checkbutton_vars:
        print(var.get())

def clear_all():
    for entry in entries:
        entry.delete(0, "end")
    for var in spinbox_vars:
        var.set(0)
    for var in checkbutton_vars:
        var.set(False)

root = tk.Tk()

entries = []
for i in range(3):
    # Note that `entry = tk.Entry(root)` and `entry.pack()` are on 2 lines
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    entries.append(entry)

spinbox_vars = []
for i in range(3):
    var = tk.IntVar(root)
    spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, textvariable=var)
    spinbox.pack()
    spinbox_vars.append(var)

checkbutton_vars = []
for i in range(3):
    var = tk.BooleanVar(root)
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=var)
    checkbutton.pack()
    checkbutton_vars.append(var)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear All", command=clear_all)
button.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Print All", command=print_all)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It puts 3 entries, `Spinbox`es, and 3 `Checkbutton`s in lists. After that I can iterate over each list and call `.get()` or `.set(...)` to get/set the value in the widget.

Comment: Okay let me check !

Comment: Can I use same with place() ?..and how!

Comment: @tanmaythakur Instead of `.pack()` just use `.place(...)`

Comment: Yeah but how if I want to place it randomly won't it affect my loop?

Comment: @tanmaythakur It really shouldn't effect the loop. The only problem with loops is if you use `lambda`s but I am guessing you aren't using them.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot !